# excel vba: show message on dropdown list selection change if changed more than once?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a piece of vba code which will generate a message to the user when a user selects a value from a dropdown list/validation list in excel.

So far my script does this fine. However, I want the user to be able to select their first value from the dropdown list without getting a message, and then on the second, third or fourth time etc, if they should change their selection in the dropdown list I want the message to display.

Can someone please show me a way of doing this? Thanks in advance

```
'Check number of times a user has changed their selection
    Dim rM As Range
    Set rM = Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If Intersect(Target, rM) Is Nothing Then
    Else
       MsgBox "changed"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ..

```
Private BooRangeSelected as Boolean
```

... at the very top of the VBA code.
Set this value to False in the Initialize event.
Set this value to True when the dropdown list is updated.
If the value is already True when the dropdown list is selected then issue the message.

I'm assuming this macro is attached to a Workbook rather than a Form stored in "personal.xlsb". In Excel / view code double click the "ThisWorkbook" icon (see below

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
    Private BooRangeSelected as Boolean
    BooRangeSelected = False
End Sub
```

This sets the variable to False once the Worksheet is opened. You can then set this to True once the dropdown has been selected

```
BooRangeSelected = True
```

Comment: please could you show me how I would incorporate this and set it to true/false?